# How do I get the content from the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have converted a GraphObject into an array.

How do I get just the names instead of the whole array? 
Like: 
You are friend with..

```
Bruce Willis
John Travolta
```

How my code looks like:

```
$friends = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends' ))
    ->execute()
    ->getGraphObject()
    ->asArray();
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $friends,1 ) . '</pre>';
```

And the results looks like this for the moment:
[image: a busy cat]

Comment: `$arr['data'][0]->name`. Just follow the keys "down" in the dump output.

Comment: Which part causes a problem? Accessing elements of an array, or properties of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($friends['data'] as $friend) {
    echo $friend->name . "<br />";
}
```

You want to loop through the data array, and store them all in the variable `$friend`, `$friend` is an object with `id` and `name` attribute, so you can call them like this: `$friend->name` and `$friend->id`

Comment: Thanks. A lot better than the php documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the `data` array and fetch the name property of each object.

Here's an example of getting all names into another array:

```
$namesArray = [];
foreach($friends['data'] as $f) {
    $namesArray[] = $f->name;
}
// print
echo '<pre>', print_r( $namesArray,1 ), '</pre>';
```

If you want the associative array (id=>name), you can do this:

```
foreach($friends['data'] as $f) {
    $namesArray[$f->id] = $f->name;
}
```

Comment: Seems like we have a downvote psycho on the run here.

Comment: +1, your answer isn't the most accurate but it's still right so it shouldn't have negative votes

Comment: Why would you do two iterations when you can print the data in the first one?

Comment: @Aboca Like almost everywhere, there are idiots on SO as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Aboca I'm not sure what the OP wants to do with the names... If he wants to print, then yes, I'd do it in a single loop. But maybe he wants it for something else, that's why I gave him an array so he can do whatever he wants with it (my print_r is just to show him the structure of the new array).

Comment: Oh true, he never says to print it. Sorry, I missed that part.

Comment: @Aboca No worries, `print_r` is okay for debugging, but I'd never use it to render something in the production code. :)